# Json move to next item

Tags: android, json

I have a dynamic JSON string that looks like this:

```
{"_id":"7","food_name":"Fiber Balance"},{"_id":"8","food_name":"Sport +"}
```

I am able to get the first name, but not the second one. This is my code for getting the first (Fiber Balance):

```
// Dynamic text
TextView textViewDynamicText = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewDynamicText);
String stringJSON = textViewDynamicText.getText().toString();

String stringFoodname = "";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringJSON);
    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        try {
            stringFoodname = jsonObject.getString("food_name");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), stringFoodname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Something went wrong!
        }
    }
} catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
    // Something went wrong!
}
```

How can I go to the next item in the json string?

Comment: What you have here is not well formed JSON. However, you can convert it to JSON by enclosing it in `[` and `]`. Then you can process it as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple data than you need to use Array,if you want to get all data from your json use below trick,

```
  String json = "{\"_id\":\"7\",\"food_name\":\"Fiber Balance\"},{\"_id\":\"8\",\"food_name\":\"Sport +\"}";
            json = "[" + json + "]";
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String foodName = object.getString("food_name");
                    Log.e("FoodName:", foodName);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("error", "json", e);
            }
```